# Como aninhar step definitions dentro de outro usando Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Gostaria que me ajudassem a resolver esta dúvida, estou tentando referenciar um `step definition` dentro de outro no mesmo arquivo para evitar repetição de código, claro se isso for possível.

Exemplo

```
Dado /^escolho a letra (.*) $/ do |letter|
# algum codigo aqui
end

Dado /^entro com a letra (.*) (.*) vezes$/ do |letter, number|
# repito aqui o step anterior usando 'number.times do' ou algo parecido do
# step anterior
end
```

Isso aqui é apenas um simples exemplo para passar uma ieia do que quero.
ainda sou iniciante então qualquer erro me avisem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O exemplo abaixo serve para aninhar vários steps e repetir quantas vezes chegar via parâmetro.

```
Dado /^escolho a letra (.*) $/ do |letter|
  @page.do_someting letter
end

Dado /^entro com a letra (.*) (.*) vezes$/ do |letter, number|
  #fiz a conversão pq ele vai chegar como string
 number.to_i.times do
    steps % (
    E escolho a letra \"#{letter}"\
    E escolho a cor \"(.*)"\
      ) 
   end
end
```

O exemplo abaixo serve para usar apenas um step

```
Dado /^escolho a letra (.*) $/ do |letter|
  @page.do_someting letter
end

Dado /^entro com a letra (.*) (.*) vezes$/ do |letter, number|
  number.to_i.times do
    step "E escolho a letra \"#{letter}"\"
  end
end
```